# JS How to change timezone without changing locale (time format)

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, datetime-format

I get time from backend as number.
I set the date by:

```
const time = 1571307720000;
const date = new Date();
date.setTime(time);
date.toLocaleString();
```

I will get timezone from backend and I want to set it in toLocaleString() but I don't want to change locale(time format) but in every page I see:

```
date.toLocaleString('es-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Seoul' })
```

and I can't use date.toLocaleString function without first string.

Is it possible to set timezone but use locale time format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MDN entry for [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString),

> See the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)constructor for details on these parameters and how to use them.

And the entry for [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) says,

> To use the browser's default locale, pass an empty array.

**So:**

```
date.toLocaleString([], { timeZone: 'Asia/Seoul' })
```